# Why are Typescript Mapped Tuple Types behaving differently when supplying Generic type vs direct type?

Tags: typescript, tuples

```
export type MyTuple = ["test", "othertest"];

type NotWorking = {
    [K in keyof MyTuple]: { value: MyTuple[K]};
};

type NotWorkingLengthType = NotWorking["length"]; // { value: 2 }

type Working<T>= {
    [P in keyof T]: { value: T[P] };
};

type MappedWorking = Working<MyTuple>;
type MappedWorkingLengthType = MappedWorking["length"]; // 2
```

Why is it behaving differently in that case ? That puzzles me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually looks like a bug, see [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995).

---

Generally mapped types of the form `{[K in keyof T]: ...T[K]...}` are considered to be *homomorphic* mapped types, and the structure of the input type `T` is preserved as much as possible.  This happens with optional and `readonly` keys (see [microsoft/TypeScript#12563](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12563)), and was also the intent when [mapped tuples/arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) were implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#26063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063).

In order for that to work, it means the compiler must look at `[K in keyof T]` and remember to keep `T` around after it has evaluated `keyof T`.  This happens when `T` is a generic type, and for optional/`readonly` keys this also happens when `T` is some concrete type:

```
type MyObj = { a?: string, readonly b: number };
type MyMappedObj = { [K in keyof MyObj]: { value: MyObj[K] } }
/* type MyMappedObj = {
    a?: {
        value: string | undefined;
    } | undefined;
    readonly b: {
        value: number;
    };
} */
```

**Note** that this only works when your mapped type is explicitly iterating over keys with *exactly* "`in keyof`".  If you calculate your keys some other way, or assign them to a type alias, or even just parenthesize the `keyof` expression, the spell is broken and the mapped type is no longer homomorphic:

```
type MyBadMappedObj = { [K in (keyof MyObj)]: { value: MyObj[K] } }
/* type MyMappedObj = {
    a: { // not optional
        value: string | undefined; 
    } 
    b: { // not readonly
        value: number;
    };
} */
```

So, mapping over keys like `{[K in keyof T]: ...}` should preserve the structure of `T` in the output.

---

Unfortunately, when the mapped arrays/tuples feature was introduced, it looks like this was only implemented for when `T` is a generic type parameter, and not for a specific concrete type.  In [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995#issuecomment-433056847), the implementer says:

> The issue here is that we only map to tuple and array types when we *instantiate* a generic homomorphic mapped type for a tuple or array (see [#26063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063)). We should probably also do it for homomorphic mapped types with a `keyof T` where `T` is non-generic type.

and that's where it is for now.  Maybe this will eventually be fixed.  Until then, you should probably use an intermediate generic type like your `Working` example as a workaround.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyiAqBXMAbVAXjgG0AiGYAZxjIBo4yIYALYWa2gXQG4AoPkhRwAcswDq0ANYBLAHYBzOMQDefOBtIBpOPLhTgiCADN0WXAS4AuOCrgA3AIZ5swGxhz5gJLVzgBffkCBIVQxGEkoWUUAGWBFVkxkIlEJaXkFcgIEljJeOAB6AtsHZ1cbACYAkOS4SOiFAB5MAD5lW3VNEgAFXTl9QxM4TGsSpxc3YZ6-YODBWrRHMBQAE3qM9vXFRo8LYBb+UPQl1a2FOJyk4WJF5eA19MUs+IVWPJ5C4oqa4QwAeQARgArdp2RwAfhsNCgGQYUGAjhWEDkeEQcABNjk2AAtgD2AFDgtELdVoCQaptH0BkZTP9gaM7ONymYyT4ZtUCgAqBBEkn3MmgzoaCE2NSacWlCZQmAwxRwAA+cGwchWwGM8nu-HF-gVSpVao1Ky1mnhiORqPRoqFEqZkyxuPYxo0szgnIKP1QGAAQoi+SsBRSfFSABQGGks4EASgZkuZdKBbICHO5RwwfoDHXFjitEs0tulsqUiuVqvVck11p11oxmdzsbtOLxUCdBL4OrdQA)

Answer (score 0):

Tuples and Array types are only preserved for homomorphic mapped types. A homomorphic mapped type is one that maps over `keyof T`, where T is a type parameter to the type, or `K` where `K` is a type parameter of the type, with `K extends keyof T`. This behavior is described in the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063) that added preserving tuples and arrays in mapped types.

Without being specially preserved, when mapping a tuple all properties are mapped, including `length` and you get that less than useful result.

Comment: This answer makes sense but I don't know that it's true.  What would you say is different about this: `type MyObj = { a?: string, readonly b: number }; type WhyDoesThisWork = { [K in keyof MyObj]: { value: MyObj[K] } }`  Note how `WhyDoesThisWork` has an optional `a` and a readonly `b`.

Comment: @jcalz hm, you are right about that, it does appear to contradict my theory of the case. Not sure, maybe object types are special cased in some other way ? The PR is very explicit about `T` being a type parameter: `where T is some type variable`. Or maybe I'm misreading that 

Comment: I think I've figured it out; I'm writing up an answer